# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}[2,x]$: The intersection of Real-Values Ranges

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory

I'm given the collection $\mathscr{B}= \{[2,x]:x\in\mathbb{R}~\text{and}~x>2\} = \{\dots,[2,3], \dots, [2,4], \dots [2,5], \dots\}$. I get that
$$\bigcup_{B\in \mathscr{B}} B=[2,+\infty),$$
but what does
$$\bigcap_{B\in \mathscr{B}}B$$
come out to? Is this essentially asking what the following limit's value is:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}[2,x]$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $2 \in [2,x]$ for all $x\ge 2$, so we know that $2$ belongs to $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$.

The question is: what else belongs to $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$ ?

The answer is *nothing*. To see this, pick a $y > 2$. If we set $x=2+\tfrac{1}{2}(y-2)$ then $y$ *does  not* belong to $[2,x]$ and so does not belong to $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$. To belong to $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$ you need $y \in [2,x]$ for all $x$.

It follows that $\bigcap\mathscr{B} = \{2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers, concerning the intersection $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$, are correct! You also asked about this notation:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}[2,x]$$

That's actually kind of tricky. What does the limit mean? You know how to take the limit of a bunch of *numbers*, but how can you take the limit of a bunch of *sets*?

Can you translate it into an epsilon-delta definition? One approach that will work in this case is the [Hausdorff metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) on compact sets. Using the Hausdorff metric, the limit becomes meaningful, and indeed we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}[2,x]=[2,2]=\{2\}.$$

However, computing this limit is harder than just computing $\bigcap\mathscr{B}$. For a proper proof, you can't just "substitute" $2$ for $x$; you have to argue from the definition of the Hausdorff metric.

If you're willing to go beyond metric spaces, there are other ways to define convergence on sets. In particular, there's the product topology, which is pretty close to your intuition. Given a nested sequence of sets $S_0\supset S_1\supset S_2\supset\cdots$, the limit in the product topology is the same as the intersection of all the sets.